# Is Acts 4:29-31 an example of earnestly desiring spiritual gifts (1 Cor. 12:31, 14:1)?

Tags: acts, 1-corinthians, spiritual-gifts

Acts 4:29-31 (ESV)

> 29 And now, Lord, look upon their threats and grant to your servants to continue to speak your word with all boldness, 30 while you stretch out your hand to heal, and signs and wonders are performed through the name of your holy servant Jesus.” 31 And when they had prayed, the place in which they were gathered together was shaken, and they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and continued to speak the word of God with boldness.

This passage from Acts gives us insight into how the early church eagerly desired and prayed for God's miraculous intervention in evangelism, through healings, signs and wonders. Interestingly, this reminded me of Paul's words in 1 Corinthians 12:31 and 14:1:

> But earnestly desire the higher gifts. (1 Corinthians 12:31 ESV)

> Pursue love, and earnestly desire the spiritual gifts, especially that you may prophesy. (1 Corinthians 14:1 ESV)

Would it be accurate to say that Acts 4:29-31 is an illustrative example of what Paul meant by earnestly desiring spiritual gifts (1 Cor. 12:31, 14:1)?

Comment: Being "filled with the Spirit" is no necessarily the same as receiving spiritual gifts.  Balaam had the spiritual gift of prophecy but could hardly be described as being filled with the Spirit.

Comment: @Dottard - Oh, I meant their request for "healing, and signs and wonders" (verse 29). Were they praying for spiritual gifts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a question about the work of Holy Spirit that requires serious thought. In Acts 2:4, the disciples were filled with the Holy Spirit at Pentecost. Why would they fill with the Holy Spirit once again in Act 4:31? Did the Holy Spirit at Pentecost only give them the abilit to speak in tongues, and the courage to speak? Does the Holy Spirit require a refill?

In Act 4:29-30, the disciples prayed to the Lord to make wonders seen through the name of Jesus. They were not asking to receive spiritual gift to heal, perform signs and wonders. Peter heals a lame beggar described in Acts 3:1-9 indicated they had it already. In Act 4:31, the place was shaken, and the disciples were filled with the Holy Spirit and spoke the word of God boldly. It sounds like divine power was present, but we should not do excessive exegesis, for we might go sideway of the truth.

Regarding the shaking of the place in Act 4:31, it was simply because the disciples were making noise to celebrate the Lord's victory. Peter and John had proved the Holy Spirit allowed them to speak the word of God boldly. So the whole room was rejoicing.

In 1 Corinthians, the background of the event is different. The Corinthians were eager to receive spirit gifts, and they believed that speaking in tongues, prophesying, and performing miracles were sign of their spiritual status. They considered becoming apostles, prophets, or teachers as a representation of their status in the Church. All of them wanted to receive the highest gift, and some might even pretended to have the gifts.

In response, Paul explained in Acts 12:4, that there are different kinds of gifts, but the same Spirit distributes them. Gifts are given for the greater good, not for personal gain. Therefore, in Acts 12:31, Paul emphasized **"LOVE"** is the greater gift that everyone should eagerly desire for it.

In 1 Cor 13:1-3, Paul further elaborated why "Love" is an essential element of all spiritual gifts;

> 1 If I speak in the tongues[a] of men or of angels, but do not have love, I am only a resounding gong or a clanging cymbal.
>
> 2 If I have the gift of prophecy and can fathom all mysteries and all knowledge, and if I have a faith that can move mountains, but do not have love, I am nothing.
>
> 3 If I give all I possess to the poor and give over my body to hardship that I may boast, but do not have love, I gain nothing. (NIV)

Paul's teaching echoes the two greatest commandments Jesus told in Matthew 22:37-39 (NIV)

> 37 Jesus replied: “‘**Love** the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’
>
> 38 This is the first and greatest commandment.
>
> 39 And the second is like it: ‘**Love** your neighbor as yourself.’

The Bible teaches us that "God is love". When we have love in our hearts, we know that the Holy Spirit is with us. In 1 John 4:16, it says, "Whoever lives in love lives in God, and God in them".